# Visibility in PHP? context of `$this` when inherited?

Tags: php, inheritance, class-visibility

I am new to php and I was going through the documentation for the visibility. I am little confused with this example in the documentation.
when the call to `$myFoo->test()` is made, shouldn't it make a call to `Foo`s `$this->testPrivate();` . I mean shouldn't `$this` be `Foo`s Object rather than `Bar` object? . As per my knowledge(I might be wrong here) `Foo` will have kind of its own `test()` method which is inherited from `Bar` and calling `$myFoo->test()` will make a call to '$this->testPrivate' where the `$this` should be `Foo`s object `myFoo`. so How is it calling `Bar`'s `testPrivate` method?

```
class Bar 
{
public function test() {
    $this->testPrivate();
    $this->testPublic();
}

public function testPublic() {
    echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
}

private function testPrivate() {
    echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
}
}

class Foo extends Bar 
{
public function testPublic() {
    echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
}

private function testPrivate() {
    echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
}
}

$myFoo = new foo();
$myFoo->test(); // Bar::testPrivate 
            // Foo::testPublic
?>
```

Comment: The ambiguity of this constructed code should be taken as a warning sign. Avoid doing it in production code: Simply don't name two private methods the same when inheriting. If you assign the same name, the methods probably do the same, so you have code duplication. Or they look like they do the same, but don't - then they should have different names.

Answer (score 5):

`test()` is in `Bar`, and will call the highest-level methods that `Bar` **has access to**. It has access to `Foo's` `testPublic` (because it is `public`) so it can call that, but it doesn't have access to `Foo's` `testPrivate()` (because it's `private` to `Foo`) so it calls it's own `testPrivate()` instead

Comment: ...but even with `class Foo [...] public function testPrivate()` Bar::testPrivate() is invoked ;-)

Comment: yes , but how is `$this` changing its context. I am still confused ,shouldn't it be opposite ,in the sense Foo has access to **test()** because its public in **class Bar**. so Foo has its own test method inherited from Bar?

Comment: Even though php starts its lookup for the method on the instance/scope, the _context_ in this case is still `Bar`, not `Foo`. You can test that by removing Bar::testPrivate. The error message will be `Call to private method Foo::testPrivate() from context 'Bar'`. Why `Bar::testPrivate` is called even with public `Foo::testPrivate` I can only explain (right now; I'm currently an endangered species with this internet addiction thingy....) by linking to the handler code: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.16/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c#L1071